# Polynomial in algebraic extension as a factor of a different polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I am trying to show that for any polynomial $f(x)$ in $K[x]$ where $K$ is an algebraic extension of $F$, there is some polynomial in $F[x]$ that has $f$ as a factor.

I'm trying to show this by saying that $(f)$ intersects with $F[x]$ but am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: What do you mean by F here?  Any arbitrary field?

Answer (score 1):

There is a matrix $A$ over $K$ with minimum polynomial $f$ (for instance
the companion matrix). As $K$ is a finite extension of $F$ we can regard
$A$ as a map from a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ to itself,
so as a square matrix $B$ over $F$ (of $|K:F|$ times the size of $A$).
Let $g$ be the characteristic polynomial of $B$. I claim that $f\mid g$.
Considering $A$ and $B$ as endomorphisms of finite-dimensional vector
spaces, we see that as $g(B)=0$, then $g(A)=0$ and as $f$ is the minimum
polynomial of $A$ then $f\mid g$.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting approach--I had not thought about matrices. Is there any way to do this by ideals or is it a lost cause?